# ar razi commentary on sure al yusuf

Tags: quran

i'm looking for the whole commentary of ar razi to sure al yusuf but cannot find it, cause i'm writting about ar razi and i need his opinion about Al-Hurūf al-Muqatta'ah and in general the entire commentary to this sure would help me. i'd really appreciate it if you can help me by any chance.

Comment: Razi's commentary in Arabic is very easy to find online, e.g. [here](https://shamela.ws/book/23635/3141) or [here](https://waqfeya.net/book.php?bid=1372). He discusses Hurūf al-Muqatta'ah at their first occurance in Surah al-Baqarah. I don't know if there is any translation available in english if that is what you are asking for.

Comment: thank you! i read it and i didn't really understand the paragraph of نُ نَقُصُّ عَلَيْكَ أَحْسَنَ الْقَصَصِ. i dont no if you are a nativ or not but hopefully you are, cause i'm not good at arabic.